# How to keep a loggedin session continued across all the pages of my react app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase email and password as authorization please help!!

This is my App.js. I have tried with navigate but this only works in a single page have but i want to add multiple pages for different classes and there whenever a user is logged in it will redirect me to my home page instead of redirecting to the page of i intended to go to...
I would appreciate that if you can suggest me any other method than using navigate() for home page.
I want to continue my login session across my whole app

[App.js code snippet 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfJJZ.png)
[App.js code snippet 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AExS1.png)

```
import { Route, Routes, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './pages/Home';
import SignUp from './pages/SignUp';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { auth } from './firebase';
import LogIn from './pages/LogIn';
import Health from './pages/Health';

function App() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [userName, setUserName] = useState("");
  useEffect(() => {
    auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if(user) {
        navigate('/');
        setUserName(user.displayName);
        console.log(user);
      }
      else {
        navigate('/auth_signup');
        setUserName("");
      }
    });
  }, [])
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path='/auth_signup' element={<SignUp/>}/>
      <Route path='/auth_login' element={<LogIn/>}/>
      <Route path='/' element={<Home name={userName}/>}/>
    </Routes>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: refer to this article https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-set-cookies-in-reactjs

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please [don't show pictures of text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code#dont-use-screenshots-of-text). Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search. You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

Comment: code added @DougStevenson